# c# a namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Tags: c#, .net-core

Can anyone tell what is wrong here ?
I just create one folder call Models and add new class BaseEntity, and I get error.
Till now I didn't get this error when I add new class...

[image]

Comment: Please post complete code rather than a screenshot. (My guess is that you've got more than one error, and if you'd looked at the *first* error and fixed that, the rest would have gone away.

Comment: Totally newbie mistake... Thanks to all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An identifier cannot start with a number; `3DBool` in this case is invalid.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx), older but still correct: it must start with either a letter or the underscore character (including or excluding the `@` character to disambiguate it with keywords).

Answer (score 3):

Namespaces cannot start with numbers.

You will have to change the name of your model `3DBook` and then change the reference